# How to edit all the deployment of kubernetes at a time

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

We have hundreds of deployment and in the config we have imagePullPolicy set as “ifnotpresent” for most of them and for few it is set to “always” now I want to modify all deployment which has **ifnotpresent** to **always**.

How can we achieve this with at a stroke?

Ex:

```
kubectl get deployment -n test -o json | jq ‘.spec.template.spec.contianer[0].imagePullPolicy=“ifnotpresent”| kubectl -n test replace -f -
```

The above command helps to reset it for one particular deployment.

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for?  It sounds like you have the core of a script to do it already; the sort of mass update you describe isn’t a typical Kubernetes operation and the CLI and API tools don’t support it directly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kubernetes doesn't natively offer mass update capabilities. For that you'd have to use other CLI tools. That being said, for modifying existing resources, you can also use the `kubectl patch` function.

The script below isn't pretty, but will update all deployments in the namespace.

```
kubectl get deployments -o name | sed -e 's/.*\///g' | xargs -I {} kubectl patch deployment {} --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/imagePullPolicy", "value": "Always"}]'
```

Note: I used `sed` to strip the resource type from the name as kubectl doesn't recognize operations performed on resources of type `deployment.extensions` (and probably others).

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer the "kubectl patch deployment" helped to do what i want.