# How to make same change across yaml file of all the deployments present in a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I want to make same change in the yaml file for every deployment , **Is there any way to make the change across all deployments present in a namespace in batch rather than one deployment at a time ?.** I am currently using this syntax to edit yaml file of one deployment at a time -

```
kubectl edit deployment.v1.apps/nginx-deployment
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080612/how-to-edit-all-the-deployment-of-kubernetes-at-a-time/52081392

Comment: I used above approach in case like I have to update the exact docker image in all of the deployments, which works pretty fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit all the deployment of kubernetes at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080612/how-to-edit-all-the-deployment-of-kubernetes-at-a-time)

Comment: `kubectl get deploy -o name | xargs -I {} echo kubectl patch {} -p ''`

Comment: Using `kubectl edit deployment -n my-ns` will open all your deployments for edition at once. Change all you want then save/close; only changed deployments will be triggered to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get deployment -o name | sed -e 's/.*\///g' | xargs -I {} kubectl patch deployment {} --type=json -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/imagePullPolicy", "value": "Always"}]'
```

Comment: But it is making change for the current environment which may be lost once the pod is deleted , I want to make change on the yaml file itself which will make the persistent change.please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by `I want to make change on the yaml file itself which will make the persistent change`. As per docs `A Deployment’s rollout is triggered if and only if the Deployment’s Pod template (that is, .spec.template) is changed, for example if the labels or container images of the template are updated. Other updates, such as scaling the Deployment, do not trigger a rollout.`